# Filter controller result based on params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, query-string

I'm trying to filter the results that are returned from my index view based on optional params. My code is working for the first param, sinceDate. But for the second param, searchQeury, nothing is filtered out.

_controller.rb

```
def index
    since = params[:sinceDate]
    query = params[:searchQuery]
    @articles = Comfy::Cms::Page.published.all
    if since
      @articles = @articles.reject{ |a| a[:created_at] < Date.parse(since) }
    end
    if query
      @article = @articles.select{ |a| a[:label].match(/#{query}/i) }
    end
```

end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that the problem is a typo?
In the line after "if query", it should be perhaps @articles instead of @article.